# В миниатюре Вордпресс не воспроизводятся гиф, потому что Вордпресс изменяет адрес картинки миниатюры?

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress

Вордпресс, при вставке в миниатюру гифки, изменяет ее адрес, подставляя файлу его разрешение в названии изо!

Должно быть как обычно: [правильный вариант миниатюры](http://cg91812-wordpress-4.tw1.ru/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/tumblr_od0menvsaF1voa7nlo1_500.gif)
А Вордпресс изменяет так: [на выходе получается так](http://cg91812-wordpress-4.tw1.ru/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/tumblr_od0menvsaF1voa7nlo1_500-236x133.gif)
Если же, просто изменить в адресной строке (например) на правильное название, то загружается гифка
Шаблон получается добавляет, как всегда, миниатюру, НО присваивает ей отдельное название Всвязи с чем, в миниатюре находится не гиф а первый кадр гиф

ХЗ!

Тем самым, гифка не подгружается и не фурычит вообщем.
Что за фигня такая не понятно Первый раз сталкиваюсь.

Здесь можно увидеть, что получается (миниатюра записи с той же гифкой): http://cg91812-wordpress-4.tw1.ru/

Подскажите пожалуйста
С Новым годом!

```
    <div class="preview">
        <p class="thumb">
            <a class="popup-post-modal-open" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
                <?php if (has_post_thumbnail()) { ?>
                    <?php
                    $img = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id(get_the_ID()), 'pt-pinbox'); ?>
                    <?php if ($img[0] != '') { ?>
                        <img src="<?php echo $img[0]; ?>" width="<?php echo $img[1]; ?>" height="<?php echo $img[2]; ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>">
                        <?php
                    } else {
                        the_post_thumbnail('medium');
                    }
                    ?>
                <?php } else { ?>
                    <img src="<?php echo pinthis_get_skin_src(); ?>/images/no-image.png" width="333" height="333" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>">
                <?php } ?>
            </a>
        </p>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

При создании миниатюр из оригинала по дефолту в WordPress анимация всегда пропадает. Тут вам поможет любой плагин, который позволяет сохранить анимацию при ресайзе. Например, старый, но рабочий [Animated Gif Resize](https://wordpress.org/plugins/animated-gif-resize/)

Comment: Да, и все уже плагины испробовал...никак не работают они ) Вами рекомендованный попробовал Никакого изменения Что-то не контачит  Не пойму вообще..

Comment: Вот этот конкретный чем не устроил? Он стоит у меня - полет нормальный. В админке видите анимацию в медиатеке? Как в теме выводится?

Comment: Все устраивает )) но только не работают с этим шаблоном, почему-то, все плагины касающиеся гиф анимации в превью...Плагины работают на страницах постов, а в их миниатюрах никак не хотят ((

Comment: кое что у меня есть по этой проблеме:     Скрипты создающие уменьшенные копии оригиналов не умеют фреймы ГИФ обрабатывать. Вам нужно использовать оригинальную картинку... Получите ID миниатюры затем получите оригинальную картинку и выводите её...

Смотрите функции get_post_thumbnail_id() и wp_get_attachment_image_src()           не подскажите с этим?

Comment: Код покажите как в теме сделан вывод миниатюр. И вы не ответили про медиатеку

Comment: ах да..в медиатеке админки и без плагинов анимация работает, а в теме как всегда- на страницах работает, а в миниатюрах нет

Comment: <?php if ( ! 1 && $img[0] != '' ) { ?> так заработает?

Comment: Таким образом мы сделаем условие ложным, чтобы отработала вторая часть условия

Comment: <?php if ($img[0] != '') { ?>

Comment: сайт не прогружается полностью тогда

Comment: Картинка то выводится? В исходном коде она есть? Или в девтулз в хроме/фаерфоксе?

Comment: С телефона сайт накрыт серым попапом. Никуда нажать не смог. С версткой явно проблема

Comment: если править так код, то тогда ничего кроме шапки не выводится Блока с миниатюрами постов и нет вовсе С телефона css подправить только Верстка сама не тронута Можете сейчас с тел. увидеть, что не выводится

Answer (score -2):

Как полумера: поставить на превью анимацию с более-менее нормальным первым кадром, чтобы статичная миниатюра выглядела лучше